# My transfer time is enough? (Transfer at Sao Paulo - Frankfurt)

Tags: airport-transfer, gru

I have 1h 50min for transfer at Sao Paulo. I have no baggage and only a backpack.

Is it enough time for transfer from domestic to international??

Comment: The same question as usual: are both flights on the same ticket/booking, or are those two different tickets? And of course, are both flights arriving at/departing from the same airport?

Comment: Keep in mind that Sao Paulo has two airports, CGH and GRU. If you are flying from abroad into Brazil, most likely you will be arriving at GRU, from which flights to Frankfurt depart.  If you are arriving at CGH and then flying from GRU, I assure you that 2h isn't enough for a transfer.

Comment: @undefined Very good catch!

Answer (score 1):

Under typical conditions, yes. But, you should consider asking to jump the immigration queues, though the last few years, this has not required me to wait more than 30 minutes.